# Name for phrase where you just state a noun

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrases

What is this type of phrase called? What parts of speech does it employ?

Situation: your brother does something silly. You say to him: "You and your crazy antics..."

This was brought up cause I wanted to apply it to something besides "you", in this case, someone's company. I said "Oh, your company and its crazy exams..." That seems to work but is a bit stranger.

Comment: Why is this an idiom?

Comment: what would you call it?

Comment: Probably a phrase structure. I'm curious too, if there is some sort of name for this. I think an idiom is a phrase that retains a meaning that is based of off a particular culture rather than the specific words used.... like "it's raining cats and dogs".

Comment: @Chris: ah yeah it's always a mess when it rains like that.. guts everywhere. luckily i haven't been in one

Comment: I don't think there's a name for this structure, but given that I have encountered it in a whole lot of Indo-European languages, I would opine that it's rather old. A few quick searches didn't return any clear examples in the Bible, but I wouldn't be surprised at all to find cites in the writings of, say, Cicero, Plato or Homer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the *accusative of exclamation* [(google)](http://www.google.com/search?q=accusative+of+exclamation).  Similar examples include "Good morning!" "Poor thing!" or "That man and his tricks!"

Answer (score 3):

It is a noun phrase: that's all.

In this context, it is serving as a complete utterance, as is quite common in ordinary speech. Whether you regard it as a "sentence" or not is a matter of definition.